# Can a toric surface be an elliptic surface?

Tags: toric-varieties, elliptic-surfaces

It is known that a rational elliptic surface is a blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at 9 points. More precisely it is obtained as the blow-up of the base locus of a  pencil of cubic curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$. The question is, whether or not we can choose such a pencil (at least the base locus should be in the torus fixed points).

Comment: If you are asking whether the blow up of the plane at $9$ points that are base locus of a pencil of cubics can be a toric surface, then the answer is *no*.

In fact, such an elliptic surface contains infinitely many $(-1)$-curves, so in particular its Cox ring is not finitely generated.

On the other hand, any toric variety has a finitely generated Cox ring.
See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72917/number-of-1-curves-on-toric-surfaces/72920